# How to manage SSIS script component output columns and its properties programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, script-component, ssis-2017

I am developing a source in SSIS VS 2017 which calls REST API using script Component and serialises JSON and provides records which I am storing in SQL Table. 
While designing I need add output columns which are 200+ manually and set properties like data type and length manually for each and every column which is very tedious.
Can any please suggest how can I add all those columns using a program and set properties using code or may be I just create one excel and just import it and it’s done in one second.
Please help brainstorm and suggest ideas VSTA is one option but I don’t know how to do it? Where to start from!!
Thank you,
Kunal

Comment: Hi Kunal, you should be generating the entire package rather programmatically. One easy (in my view) approach would be [BIML](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2015/02/creating-biml-script-component.html)

Comment: since you tagged the question with c#, i think you may follow the first section of the provided answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I totally agree with @Arthur comment, you should build the whole package programmatically. You have two approaches to create packages programatically:*

## (1) Build SSIS using C#

If you are familiar with C# you have two choices:

**(a) Using SQL Server Client SDK assemblies**

This is the official traditional way to create ssis packages programmatically, there are many link on the internet that you can refer to such as:

- [Creating a Package Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/creating-a-package-programmatically?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Samples for creating SSIS packages programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/12/30/samples-for-creating-ssis-packages-programmatically/)
- [Creating and Executing an SSIS Package Programmatically](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/on-the-fringe/2013/08/25/creating-and-executing-an-ssis-package-programmatically/)
- [Building Packages Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/building-packages-programmatically?view=sql-server-2017)

**(b) Using EzApi – Alternative package creation API**

> EzAPI is a .NET library written in C# by Evgeny Koblov one of the testers on the SSIS team to abstracts away a lot of the cumbersome low-level coding needed to create SSIS packages XML directly in a programming language

- [GitHub - EzApi2016](https://github.com/fpvmorais/EzApi2016)
- [NuGet Gallery - EzApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzAPI/)

There are many link on the internet that you can refer to such as:

- [EzAPI – Alternative package creation API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/12/30/ezapi-alternative-package-creation-api/)
- [EzAPI Overview](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2012/01/ezapi-overview.html)
- [EzApi a C# library for creating SSIS packages programatically](https://www.kapacity.dk/ezapi-a-c-library-for-creating-ssis-packages-programatically/?lang=en)
- [Getting Started with EzAPI](https://www.dimodelo.com/blog/2013/getting-started-with-ezapi/)

## (2) Build SSIS using BIML

If you are familiar with XML, then you should use BIML (Business Intelligence Markup Language) which is a markup language developed by Varigence and can be integrated within Visual Studio to create packages without the need of coding experience.

- [Biml Website](http://bimlscript.com/)

There are many links that you can refer to learn BIML:

- [One Learning Path for Biml](https://andyleonard.blog/2018/06/one-biml-learning-path/)
- [Introduction to Business Intelligence Markup Language (BIML) for SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/)

---

## Update 1 - C# approach

Recently i started a new project on Git-Hub, which is a class library developed using C#. You can use it to import tabular data from excel, word , powerpoint, text, csv, html, json and xml into SQL server table with a different schema definition using schema mapping approach. check it out at:

- [SchemaMapper: C# Schema mapping class library](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper)

You can follow this Wiki page for a step-by-step guide:

- [Import data from multiple files into one SQL table step by step guide](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper/wiki/Import-data-from-multiple-files-into-one-SQL-table-step-by-step-guide)

You can use this library to read from json and import into SQL *(without changing the schema) with a few lines of code*.

Comment: @Kunal at the end if you agreed with this answer accept it or if you find another solution write it as your own answer

Comment: No, this is not the pin point answer I need answer which direct addresses the issue. Generating Cade based component is not the answer I am ok with. There had to be a better way that’s what I believe.

Comment: @Kunal it will be very interesting if you find another approach. Don't hesitate to share such information. Hope you will find a better solution. Good luck

Comment: @Kunal not that i am not asking to accept my answer if it doesn't fits your need, i leaved this comment since you have recently registered in SO.

Comment: Well I believe Microsoft should think about it, solution should be simple writing whole lot of code for just this is not justified that is a simple requirement and should be available built in by Microsoft other components of SSIS have it where it allows to copy and paste from visual studio to excel and vice-versa.

Comment: Hadi and everyone answering me I do respect all your suggestions and want to find out best possible way of doing it so will update this post in sometime. If I get anything.

Comment: @Kunal are you familiar with c#?

Comment: I am a bit new to C# not very proficient as of now.

Comment: sure let me check. Thank you.